# jQuery KeyUp Not Allowing More Values

Tags: jquery, onkeydown, onkeyup

I'm new to javascript (and jQuery) so bear with me.

I want the user to be able to type in a number on a textbox and each time the user enters another value (keypress, keydown, keyup) the code executes and calculates the new value.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFLEb/)

My problem is that the textbox won't let me enter more than one value. How do I keep entering more values?

jQuery (1.9.1)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.conv').keyup(function() {
      var valx = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-val'));
      var classes = parseInt($('.conv').length);

      for (var i=1;classes;i++) {
          var x = 'a' + i;
          //alert(x);
          var theval = document.getElementById(x);
            var z = parseFloat($('#' + x).attr('data-val'));
            //alert(z);
            $('#' + x).val(z / valx);
        if (i == classes) {
        break;
        }
    }
    });
 });
```

Again...here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFLEb/) if you want to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be overwriting even the value of the textbox that generated the event..

Replace

```
$('#' + x).val(z / valx);
```

with

```
$('#' + x).not(this).val(z / valx);
```

**EDIT**

The reason is you are always reading the value from

```
var valx = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-val'));
```

instead of

```
var valx = parseFloat($(this).val());
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GFLEb/2/)**

Comment: Thanks! that helps. How do I make it so that the code will redo the calculations when I keep typing in digits? Example: type "1", the code will calculate. Then add a "0" and the code does not register that the new number is "10".

Comment: in that case you may want `change()` instead of `keyup()`

Comment: .change() only seems to work when I focus away from the textbox